# Angular Fomrly and Modals - unable to update validation of form after modal input

Tags: javascript, angularjs, bootstrap-modal, angular-formly

I have created a modal that works in moving the model from the modal to the form, however if the field has `required: true`, the form will not validate if the field is touched but then checked in the modal.

I have a working [JSBin](http://jsbin.com/roboxa/edit?html,css,js,output) showing the issue.

As you can see from the example, I have tried various things to force the field to valid without any luck.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

No idea why you are moving the model to a modal and then back, it seems to serve little purpose.  I have found cases when validation doesn't always work right, this seems to be one of them.  You have two options.  Use an expression property to check a separate flag you set when you select the field to change required to false or simply set a flag and use that to check validation manually.